# Excel VBA ADO loop

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

my question might be simple, but I am having trouble finding an appropriate solution.

I have a couple of Excel spreadsheets, in the first one I have filled a column A with unique 6 digits IDs

Then, using ADO connection, I need to get information that corresponds to each of these unique IDs from the second spreadsheet (which contains a huge amount of data)

So far I implement the code below, yet I am pretty sure this is not the best, or fastest, way to do it (As it awfully slow)

Sure, I have a VBA routine which will do this without ADO, yet the amount of info is getting larger and soon it will become a problem.

Hope ADO can help me to manage it, thanks

```
Sub UpdateCurrentStatus()
    Dim sSQLQry As String
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    Dim UID As String


    If MsgBox("Is the Labinal extract up-to-date?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DBPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select second spreadsheet", FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")

    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';FMT=Delimited(;)"
    Conn.Open sconnect

    y = 2
    Do
        UID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value

        sSQLSting = "SELECT [CurrentPhase] From [LabinalExtract$] where TicketReference =" & UID ' Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])"

        mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

        Sheets(1).Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

        mrs.Close

         y = y + 1

    Loop While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1) <> ""

    Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows in you data file, and how many ID's are you querying?  Do you expect always to get either zero or no records returned from the query?

Comment: You overwrite your output with each loop as `CopyFromRecordset` location never changes.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth, sorry, didnt realice I was overwriting the output, will correct, thanks for your feedback still I will check further for the loop topic

Answer (score 1):

Consider avoiding any looping and simply connect both workbooks in SQL as Windows' Jet/ACE Engine allows inline querying of Excel workbooks, Access databases, even text files.

Below assumes your column header in main workbook of unique IDs is named *Column1* (change SQL's `SELECT` and `ON` clauses if otherwise) in worksheet named *Sheet1*. Additionally it is unclear if you are connecting to CSV file or Excel workbook. This assumes both are Excel workbooks.

```
' CURRENT WORKBOOK CONNECTION (LAST SAVED STATE)
xlConn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
              & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

' JOIN QUERY WITH INLINE EXTERNAL CONNECTION
sSQLSting = "SELECT t1.Column1, t2.[CurrentPhase]" _
               & " FROM [Sheet1$] t1" _
               & " INNER JOIN" _
               & "     (SELECT * FROM" _
               & "     [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & DBPath & "].[LabinalExtract$]) t2" _
               & " ON t1.Column1 = t2.TicketReference"

' OUTPUT QUERY RESULTS
mrs.Open sSQLSting, xlConn

Sheets(1).Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

mrs.Close
xlConn.Close
```

Comment: Actually, you are correct, the data i am trying to pull is comming from a CSV file

Comment: To try the code you kindly provided I had saved the CSV as Excel file and tried the code, but I am getting an error  "too few parameters. Expected 1." for the following line:     & " ON t1.Column1 = t2.TicketReference"     , checked and the header is not mispelled, have you any idea what may be causing this? thanks

Comment: Yes they do both begin in A1

Comment: Manage to get beyond that, now I get the same error in line:  mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

Comment: That's the same error spot as query is called on that line. All I can say is be very sure of column and worksheet names (before/after/between spaces, special chars, etc.). Adjust actual SQL in code to point to actual names. Other than I cannot recreate your error which translates as either *Column1* in first workbook or *TicketReference* or *CurrentPhase* in second workbook cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, managed to make it work, didnt know that ".[LabinalExtract$]" was a reference to an actual table name within the file, now it Works, well , almost, In the file where I have all the IDs the code is pasting the current phase along with the IDs, so I have it duplicated, any advice in how to reduce the output just to the current phase? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I managed to succeed adapting the code kindly provided by Parfait, now is working, hope it may help anyone else

Be careful as in the line:

```
& "     [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & DBPath & "].[Labinal]) t2" _
```

[Labinal] refers to a named range (table) in Excel

Secondly in this line:

```
sSQLSting = "SELECT t2.[CurrentPhase]" _
```

You select the data you want back, in this case I reduce it to the column named "Current phase" in the Excel file I used as database (Included in the range name as "Labinal")

Here the final code:

```
Sub UpdateCurrentStatus()
    Dim sSQLQry, sSQLSting As String
    Dim ReturnArray
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

    If MsgBox("Is the Labinal extract up-to-date?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DBPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Selecciona el extracto de iMade", FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")


    ' CURRENT WORKBOOK CONNECTION (LAST SAVED STATE)
    Conn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm,    *.xlsb)};" _
              & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

    ' JOIN QUERY WITH INLINE EXTERNAL CONNECTION
    sSQLSting = "SELECT t2.[CurrentPhase]" _
               & " FROM [Sheet1$] t1" _
               & " INNER JOIN" _
               & "     (SELECT * FROM" _
               & "     [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & DBPath & "].[Labinal]) t2" _
               & " ON t1.Column1 = t2.TicketReference"

    ' OUTPUT QUERY RESULTS
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    Sheets(1).Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

mrs.Close
Conn.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.  Use sub procedure.

```
Sub myQuery()
Dim y As Integer
y = 2
Do
     UID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1).Value

    sSQLSting = "SELECT [CurrentPhase] From [LabinalExtract$] where TicketReference =" & UID ' Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])"
     y = y + 1

Loop While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1) <> ""

End Sub
Sub UpdateCurrentStatus(sSQLQry As String)
'Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
Dim UID As String


If MsgBox("Is the Labinal extract up-to-date?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


DBPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select second spreadsheet", FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';FMT=Delimited(;)"
Conn.Open sconnect

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).CopyFromRecordset mrs

    mrs.Close

    Set mrs = Nothing
Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will let you know how it goes